# Hybrid Application - Map Integration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-native, ionic2

I am working on a mobile application using (React-Native) and basically the main functionality on which I am currently working on is:.

- Map Integration: *Partially Success* - I am successful in doing all the things which are mentioned in this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps). The remaining things is to **show live routing based on my current location from origin to destination.**

---

Below is the code I am using to render the View:

```
            <View style={ styles.container }>
                <MapView
                initialRegion = {{
                    latitude: this.state.origin.latitude,
                    longitude: this.state.origin.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
                }}
                ref={(ref) => { this.mapRef = ref }}
                onLayout = {() => this.mapRef.fitToCoordinates([{longitude: this.state.origin.longitude, latitude: this.state.origin.latitude}, {longitude: this.state.destination.longitude, latitude: this.state.destination.latitude}], { edgePadding: { top: 100, right: 10, bottom: 200, left: 10 }, animated: true })}
                provider={ PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
                style={ styles.map }
                showsUserLocation={ true }
                followsUserLocation={true}
                loadingEnabled={true}
                overlays={[{
                    coordinates: this.state.routeCoordinates,
                    strokeColor: '#19B5FE',
                    lineWidth: 10
                }]}
                >
                    <MapView.Marker
                    coordinate={ this.state.origin }
                    />
                    <MapView.Marker
                    coordinate={ this.state.destination }
                    />
                    <MapViewDirections
                    origin={this.state.origin}
                    destination={this.state.destination}
                    apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
                    strokeWidth={5}
                    strokeColor={'#000000'}
                    mode={'driving'}
                    onStart={(params) => {
                        console.log('Your journey has been started');
                    }}
                    onReady={(result) => {
                        console.log('Reach to the starting point to start journey');
                    }}
                    onError={(errorMessage) => {
                        alert(errorMessage);
                    }}
                    />

                </MapView>
                <View style={styles.bottomBar}>
                    <View style={styles.bottomBarGroup}>
                        <Text style={styles.bottomBarHeader}>Directions</Text>
                        {this.state.directions.map((directionsObj, index) => (
                            <Text key={index} style={styles.bottomBarContent}>{directionsObj.html_instructions}
                            </Text>
                        ))}
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
```

But this code only show the map between the origin and the destination, I want to show the live navigation between the origin and the destination. Like *Cab Booking* application.

Comment: This question is far too broad - please narrow it down the particular aspect of the map integration you're having issues with (preferably with example code).

Comment: @JoeClay How to implement the "live routing based on my current location from origin to destination". I am using the below module to implement this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps

Comment: @JoeClay I think now my question is specific to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It working for me. You have to use google direction API to get all possible location points between origin and destination.

once you get all points, you can use polygons to connects that points, it will draw route between your origin and destination.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,Dimensions
} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';


const mode = 'driving'; // 'walking';
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;
const SPACE = 0.01;
const DEFAULT_PADDING = { top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100 };
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class App extends Component<{}> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);  
    this.mapRef = null;    
  }

  state = {    
    MARKERS : null,
    origin :'22.9962,72.5996',
    destination :'23.0134,72.5624',    
    destMarker : '',
    startMarker :'',
    imageloaded:false,
  }

  componentWillMount()
  {
    this.getRoutePoints(this.state.origin,this.state.destination);
  }

  /**
   * This method will give you JSON response with all location points between 2 location
   */
  getRoutePoints(origin,destination) {
    console.log("-----getRoutePoints-----")    
    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${origin}&destination=${destination}&key=YOUR API KEY&mode=${mode}`;
    console.log("URL -- >>" + url);

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (responseJson.routes.length) {
          var cortemp = this.decode(responseJson.routes[0].overview_polyline.points) // definition below;
          var length = cortemp.length - 1;

          var tempMARKERS = []; 
          tempMARKERS.push(cortemp[0]) ;   //start origin        
          tempMARKERS.push(cortemp[length]); //only destination adding

          console.log("tempMARKERS : " + JSON.stringify(tempMARKERS));

          this.setState({
            coords: cortemp,            
            MARKERS:tempMARKERS,
            destMarker : cortemp[length],
            startMarker:cortemp[0],
          });

        }
      }).catch(e => { console.warn(e) });
  }

  /**
   * This method will transforms something like this geocFltrhVvDsEtA}ApSsVrDaEvAcBSYOS_@... to an array of coordinates
   */

  decode(t, e) {
    for (var n, o, u = 0, l = 0, r = 0, d = [], h = 0, i = 0, a = null, c = Math.pow(10, e || 5); u < t.length;) {
      a = null, h = 0, i = 0;
      do a = t.charCodeAt(u++) - 63, i |= (31 & a) << h, h += 5; while (a >= 32);
      n = 1 & i ? ~(i >> 1) : i >> 1, h = i = 0;
      do a = t.charCodeAt(u++) - 63, i |= (31 & a) << h, h += 5; while (a >= 32);
      o = 1 & i ? ~(i >> 1) : i >> 1, l += n, r += o, d.push([l / c, r / c])
    }
    return d = d.map(function (t) {
      return {
        latitude: t[0],
        longitude: t[1]
      }
    })
  }

  /**
   * After loading custome image of marker it will render map and refresh map will image
   */
  forceUpdateMap() {
    console.log("-----forceUpdateMap------")
    this.setState({ imageloaded: true });
  }

  /**
   * This method will fit all markers point into single screen 
   */
  fitAllMarkers() {
    const temMark = this.state.MARKERS;
    console.log( "------fitAllMarkers------")
    this.setState({loading:false});
    if (this.mapRef == null) {
      console.log("map is null")
    } else {
      //option:1  
      console.log("temMark : " + JSON.stringify(temMark));
      this.mapRef.fitToCoordinates(temMark, {
        edgePadding: DEFAULT_PADDING,
        animated: false,
      });              
    }
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
          (this.state.coords != null) ?
            <MapView
              ref={ref => { this.mapRef = ref; }}
              style={styles.map}
              onLayout={() => this.fitAllMarkers()}>

              {/*used to drae line on rout point of locations*/}
              < MapView.Polyline
                coordinates={this.state.coords}
                strokeWidth={2}
              />

              {/*start point marker*/}
              <MapView.Marker
                key={1}
                coordinate={this.state.startMarker}
              />

              {/*end point marker*/}
              <MapView.Marker
                key={2}
                coordinate={this.state.destMarker}
              >                
              </MapView.Marker>
            </MapView> : null
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});
```

Comment: Mistakenly, you have posted your API key.